# layer control in iWatch using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there any way to layer a control on top of another. I wanted to put one label on top of another to build out a word. I am using Xamarin Studio and programming for the iWatch, watchOS2.

Comment: You should consider reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: I re-reading it I think you are correct.My comment below explains it more fully. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike UIKit, there is no z-index, or hierarchy, in WatchKit for views. As far as I know, the closest you can get to this is to use a `WKInterfaceGroup` with a custom background. The hard way, which may get you the result you are looking for, is to render an image and display it.

Comment: I was hoping to layer one text box upon another and have the same word be spelled out in both. The one in the foreground would be a brighter color and as the word was built (i.e. letters added) it would look like the word being built. I wanted to have the word be dynamic so that for each time I ran the program a new word or words could be selected. Sounds like that would be hard if I were building it dynamically.